# How to initialize and return structs inline?

Tags: syntax, struct, return, d

I want to initialize a structure and return it, on the same line in Digitalmars D. How do I do this?

```
struct Record {
    immutable(ubyte) protocolVersion;
    immutable(ubyte) type;
    immutable(ushort) requestId;
}

class test {
    Record nextRequest() {
        ubyte buffer[512];
        auto bytesReceived = socketIn.receive(buffer);
        if(bytesReceived < 0)
            throw new ErrnoException("Error while receiving data");
        else if(bytesReceived == 0)
            throw new ConnectionClosedException();

        return {
            protocolVersion:1, //52
            type:1, //53
            requestId:1 //54
        }; //55
    } //56
} // 57
```

This code gives me compile errors:

```
file.d(53): Error: found ':' when expecting ';' following statement
file.d(54): Error: found ':' when expecting ';' following statement
file.d(55): Error: expression expected, not '}'
file.d(56): Error: found '}' when expecting ';' following return statement
```

Comment: why the immutable, that makes it impossible to copy or assign to the record...

Comment: Can't a member variable of a structure be immutable as long as it's initialized in the constructor? (similar to Java's final) I know this behaviour exists within classes.

Comment: yeah but then it can't be copied, remember they are always passed by value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C style {} syntax is only available in a top declaration

```
SomeStruct c = { foo, bar, etc}; // ok
```

but returning it like you do won't work - in other contexts, { stuff } means function literal.

```
return {
    writeln("cool");
};
```

For example will try to return a void function() and you'll see a type mismatch.

The way that works best with D is to use a constructor style syntax. It won't do named members, but works anywhere:

```
return Record(1, 1, 1);
```

Each argument there fills in a member of the struct. So Record(1,2,3) sets protocolVersion to 1, type to 2, and requestId to 3.

You can also define struct constructors to customize this behavior, the syntax there is `this(int arg, int arg2) { currentVersion = arg; /* and whatever else */ }` but you don't have to define a constructor if you just want to fill in all the members. `return Record(1,1,1);` will work with your code as you have it.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way by far is to simply call the default constructor.

```
return Record(1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: That's not a default constructor. Structs in D don't have default constructors. A default constructor is a constructor that takes no arguments. `Record(1, 1, 1)` calls a normal constructor, though in this case, it's one that's generated by the compiler (since none was declared). So, I'm guessing that the fact that it's generated is what made it so that you incorrectly used the term "default constructor."

Comment: Yep, that would be exactly the reason I called it a default constructor.